# Map an hibernate Char (using JPA) to accept only two possible values: U or D

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, char

I want to restrict my spring object to accept only two possible values: 'U' or 'D' (Updated/Deleted)
I have limited it to accept only one character

```
@Size(max = 1)
private String currentValue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways, partly depending on what exactly you mean by "restrict".

The `@Size(max = 1)` annotation doesn't really restrict the value in your object. You can still put a large part of the bible in it since it is still a `String`.
It just won't make it to the database because the annotation triggers a validation and in generated DDL statements it will limit the datatype in the database to something like `VARCHAR(1)`

If you want something similar you can create a custom validation annotation.
I.e. you will create your own annotation plus the code that validates the rule you want to enforce. [The Hibernate documentation describes it rather well I think](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html).

This doesn't include anything about your database schema, so you might want to add a custom check constraint to the schema.
The [exact syntax differs by database](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) it seems but in general you use a condition as you would is in the where-clause of a select statement: `current_value in ('U', 'D')`

But I really think using a `String` for this is a wrong choice to start with.
If you create an `Enum` having the two values `U` and `D` and configuring the property to use the name not the ordinal value for representing it in the database you wouldn't need any validation.

Of course you still have the ugly, mostly meaningless names.
You could change those to something that is readable, which will change the database representation as well.
And if your database supports it you might change the database representation to an `Enum` there as well. 
[Vlad Mihalcea describes how to do that.](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

If your database does not support enums and you don't want the long String values nor the oridinal value of an enum in you database you can write your own user type. [Here is an article how to do that](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types).